# viewWillDisappear equivalent for CCScenes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a `viewWillDisappear` equivalent for `CCScenes` ?

Just Like the method `onExit` which is an equivalent of `viewDidDisappear` or `onEnter` which is an equivalent of `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an equivalent. The closest you have is `onExit` or `dealloc` (not recommended).